# Force UITableView to scroll to top?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

How would you go about forcing a UITableViewCell to scroll to the top if the tableview contains less than 10 or so cells? I support editing of Managed Object Contexts within my tableView cells while the tableview is in editing mode. Needless to say, if a cell is at the bottom of the tableview, it gets blocked by the keyboard when a user goes to edit the title or location of an event. I tried a solution like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if(_selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
        _selectedIndex = -1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }

    if(_selectedIndex >= 0){
        NSIndexPath *previous = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_selectedIndex inSection:0];
        _selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previous]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    _selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [tableView rowHeight]*indexPath.row) animated:YES];
}
```

But this does not keep the tableview at the contentOffset. it will snap to the top and then snap back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you consider sliding the whole tableview up?

**edit:** I did find something that looks like it does what you're looking for:
[Code here](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-drop-in-universal-solution-for-moving-text-fields-out-of-the-way-of-the-keyboard/).

This code shrinks the inset of the table view from the bottom, which then allows it display one of those lower cells without snapping back down.

Comment: do i just drop in the source code tableview.h and .m files into my existing project? i'm not using a UITableViewController, only a UITableView

Comment: and i'm not using a .xib or storyboard for that matter... everything was laid out in one view controller (to support slide left/right animations) using self sufficient subviews

Comment: Just Grab the TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView.m/.h files and set your UITableView instance to be an instance of that isntead. You do not need to have a xib or a UITableViewController. Alternatively, you can just rip out the code you need from it and put it in your view controller and not subclass it at all. If this turns out not to be a suitable solution for some reason I will try to help you further.

Comment: i'm not sure if i implemented it correctly, but just dropping it in and changing my tableview does not do anything. all of my tableview functionality works but it doesn't slide. i forgot to mention that the editing only happens while the tableview is in editing mode

Comment: I got this to work, only it created another problem for me... My tableView cells expand, but do not collapse properly. It actually crashes if I try to collapse a cell

Comment: I'm going to see if i can make this work and get back to you.

Comment: I set up a project with a tableview whose cells contain textfields. After I completed it, I dropped in the class I linked you to(without making any other changes), and it seems to work fine. [Here](https://github.com/dim1014/stackoverflow_11269148) is a link to the code on github.

Answer (score 12):

I like the following solution because it also scrolls to the top of a header view if you have one.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably should use this method on UITableView:

```
-(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Essentially what you do is that when the [tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] method of your UITableViewDelegate gets called, you pass the index of that selection to the above method and set scrollposition = UITableViewScrollPositionTop.

That will scroll the selected cell to the top of the screen and out of the way of the keyboard.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you scroll a cell to the top that would otherwise be visible if it was at the bottom (if there are too few cells), then it will just bounce back down.

Comment: The method I mention above will solve the problem of keeping the edited cell visible. But you will NOT be able to keep the cell from following the keyboard back down, when it is dismissed if it is the last cell for example. Simply nothing you can do about that except add dummy or empty cells.

Comment: While scrolling at top of the list if you want also to show header use  UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle

Answer (score 2):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can also use:

```
[mainTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this? :

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

The sample is:

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in my case, also it scrolls to headear's top If you have:

```
  **myTablView.scrollRectToVisible((myTablView.rectForHeader(inSection: 0), to: myTablView.superview).0, animated: true)**
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614872-rectforheader

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to scroll to top your `tableView`

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true).
```

Answer (score 0):

More specified answer to your question:

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToBottom(){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(
                row: self.numberOfRows(inSection:  self.numberOfSections -1) - 1, 
                section: self.numberOfSections - 1)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func scrollToTop() {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
            self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```